# Get source control in OnServerValidate method

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I have a CustomValidator control and within the OnServerValidate event i want to set properties of the control that is being validated.

You would think the validated control object would be available in the OnServerValidate event, but it is not. I then tried to do a FindControl but can't seem to get access to the ControlToValidate value.

Would someone please help me get the TextBox control being validated so that i can modify its properties from the OnServerValidate event?

Thanks,
D

Comment: If you know what control is being validated, why can't you access it directly? Is it nested in a databound control or something?

Comment: I'm attempting to create a "universal" CustomValidator even that will be used by many different controls.

Comment: @JamesJohnson I have the same issue, and the reason why I can't just hard code the control is because I want to use the same validation function for three different fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
   var validationControl = source as CustomValidator;

   var textBox = FindControl(validationControl.ControlToValidate) as TextBox;

   if (textBox != null)
   {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Slightly different but you got it!!

ContentPlaceHolder placeholder = Master.FindControl("placeholder_content") as ContentPlaceHolder;

CustomValidator validationControl = source as CustomValidator;
TextBox textBox = placeholder.FindControl(validationControl.ControlToValidate) as TextBox;
if (textBox != null)
{

}

Answer (score 9):

I tried the above answer but as my TextBox was in a ListView in a ContentPlaceHolder it all got a bit out of hand. I ended up using this which should work in all circumstances:

```
string textBoxName = ((CustomValidator)source).ControlToValidate;
var textBox = ((CustomValidator)source).Parent.FindControl(textBoxName) as TextBox;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

for get value:

```
string number = args.Value;
```